# Why I can't loop this function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops

My teacher gave us a lesson where we had to find out how many times a x number was drawn in the lottery. He gave us a .txt document containing all datas from the previous years. He told us to build a function to discover these values. I ended up with this:

```
//Transfer the txt logs to variable 'conteudo'

try {
  conteudo = fs.readFileSync("dados.txt", "utf8");
  conteudo = conteudo.split("\r\n");
  vezessort = 0;
} catch(erro) {
  console.error(erro.message);
}

//Function created to review all the lines in the txt file
//First for loop is to split each line, making them an array
//Second loop is to compare the values 2 to 7 on each line, where contains the numbers drawn in the lottery

function vezSort(a){
  for (i = 1; i < conteudo.length; i++){
    conteudo[i] = conteudo[i].split(";");
    for(j = 2; j < 8; j++){
      if(conteudo[i][j] == a){
        vezessort += 1;
      }
    }
  }
}

//In this exercise we need to capture the input from user, and use it as a parameter on the function

a = parseInt(prompt('Digite um número: '));
r = vezSort(a);
console.log(`O número foi sorteado ${vezessort} vezes.`);
```

It works perfectly, the final values matches with the desired output he gave. The problem is, in the next question he tell us to loop the function for each number between 1 to 60. But every attempt I try to loop I get problems with this line: `conteudo[i] = conteudo[i].split(";");`. What I am doing wrong? (Btw, in this exercise the input from the user is not needed.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're modifying the `conteudo` array when you call `vezSort()`. It's initially an array of strings, but you're changing it to a 2-dimensional array when you do `conteudo[i] = conteudo[i].split(";");`

You should either convert it to a 2-dimensional array just once, outside the `vezSort()` function, or use a local variable rather than modifying the original array.

Doint it once is more efficient, so that's how I show it:

```
try {
  conteudo = fs.readFileSync("dados.txt", "utf8");
  conteudo = conteudo.split("\r\n");
  conteudo = conteudo.map(line => line.split(';'));
  vezessort = 0;
} catch(erro) {
  console.error(erro.message);
}

//Function created to review all the lines in the txt file
//First for loop is to split each line, making them an array
//Second loop is to compare the values 2 to 7 on each line, where contains the numbers drawn in the lottery

function vezSort(a){
  for (i = 1; i < conteudo.length; i++){
    for(j = 2; j < 8; j++){
      if(conteudo[i][j] == a){
        vezessort += 1;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

`.split()` turns a string into an array of substrings, not an array into a string.  For that, use    `.join()`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

Comment: Where do you think they should be joining something instead of splitting it?